# load incremental data files in spark df

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, hdfs

I have data in Hadoop hdfs directory. there are 100 JSON files in it. I am storing those to hdfs directory through the scala API and then I am reading it in spark df  using `spark.read.json(path)`. after that, I am creating a temporary view and doing spark SQL and saving it in the different data frame(df). but the issue is every 2 min interval some more JSON files are getting appending in the same hdfs directory. so if have 100 files, then after 2 min interval I have 120  JSON files in the same directory. how can I load the same in spark df and perform spark SQL query over it?

Comment: I guess you either need to load files in a loop after some interval. or other solution would be to use spark streaming which can loads file automatically and you can set the parameters such as after how long it should look for new file and how much data it should keep at a given moment.